# Why can't we backprop the gradients in the recurrent neural nets?

Tags: backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network, gradient

We use back propagation through time in the recurrent neural nets. It's done by adding up the gradients w.r.t to weights in each time step. But my question is why can't we just keep getting the derivatives as we normally done in back prop.

Comment: Consider this: when predicting a time series x1,x2,x3 if we do not backprop through time, how do we obtain the total loss of a training sample involving not only x1 but also x2 and x3?

Comment: Related: [Why back propagate through time in a RNN?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/238496/12359)

Comment: Well you can take the loss by each time step and back prop through time. Here I am asking about single time step. Let's say we have 3 time steps. So why we add grads in each step by considering the hidden step before it is not a variable of the weight matrix.

Comment: but that is what we are doing in BPTT though. I dont see the issue.

Comment: @Pinocchio so we add the gradients and then set that sum of gradients to be our new gradients at each time step?

Comment: @tryingtolearn I think its just easier if you see what the equations are yourself. Check it out here: https://youtu.be/zQxm3Upr3_I

Its just good old backprop with an extra summation there somewhere.

Comment: also check: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-backpropagation-and-backpropagation-through-time